# Applying a map to a function's rest argument

Tags: clojure

In Clojure, if I have a function *f*,

```
(defn f [& r] ... )
```

and I have a seq *args* with the arguments I want to call f with, I can easily use *apply*:

```
(apply f args)
```

Now, say I have another function *g*, which is designed to take any of a number of optional, named arguments - that is, where the rest argument is destructured as a map:

```
(defn g [& {:keys [a b] :as m}] ... )
```

I'd normally call g by doing something like

```
(g :a 1 :b 2)
```

but if I happen to have a map *my-map* with the value {:a 1 :b 2}, and I want to "apply" g to my-map - in other words, get something that would end up as the above call, then I naturally couldn't use apply, since it would be equivalent to

```
(g [:a 1] [:b 2])
```

Is there a nice way to handle this? May I have gone off track in my design to end up with this? The best solution I can find would be

```
(apply g (flatten (seq my-map)))
```

but I surely don't like it. Any better solutions?

**EDIT:** A slight improvement to the suggested solution might be

```
(apply g (mapcat seq my-map))
```

which at least removes one function call, but it may still not be very clear what's going on.

Answer (score 6):

I have stumbled into this problem myself and ended up defining functions to expect one map. A map can have a variable amount of key/value pairs, and if flexible enough, so there is no need for & rest arguments. Also there is no pain with apply. Makes life a lot easier!

```
(defn g [{:keys [a b] :as m}] ... )
```

Comment: Thanks! That'd certainly be a way, but then the optional, named arguments that the associative rest destructuring allows would always need to be put inside a map in the function call - in particular, if you want to use none of the arguments, you'd have to do (g {}) or (g nil). 
I see now that I was unclear in the question - I'll edit to clarify that g is designed to take optional named arguments, and that the question would be how to idiomatically call it if you happen to have your arguments wrapped inside a map.

Comment: You could also use multiple arities, one for zero arguments and one for one argument: `(defn g ([] ...) ([{:keys [a b] :as m}] ...))`

Comment: Thanks! In the end I went with this solution - the reason why I ended up in this situation was that the original function was growing large, and the part using the optional arguments was well suited to be broken into its own function h. I still wanted g to be called in that same way though, then to within g call h with the optional arguments grouped into a map, rather than having to make a call to h and passing the results to g. In this particular case, your suggestion worked out well, but I wrote a simple function which works well for the original question - will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is no better direct way than converting to a seq.

You are done. You have done all you can.

It's just not really clojurish to have Common Lisp style :keyword arg functions. If you look around Clojure code you will find that almost no functions are written that way.

Even the great RMS is not a fan of them:

> "One thing I don't like terribly much is keyword arguments (8). They don't seem quite Lispy to me; I'll do it sometimes but I minimize the times when I do that." ([Source](http://www.gnu.org/gnu/rms-lisp.html))

At the moment where you have to break a complete hash map into pieces just to pass all of them as keyword mapped arguments you should question your function design.

I find that in the case where you want to pass along general options like `:consider-nil true` you are probably never going to invoke the function with a hash-map `{:consider-nil true}`.

In the case where you want to do an evaluation based on some keys of a hash map you are 99% of the time having a `f ([m & args])` declaration.

When I started out defining functions in Clojure I hit the same problem. However after thinking more about the problems I tried to solve I noticed myself using destructoring in function declaration almost never.

Comment: You may well be right. I've found it useful sometimes, and think it allows you to easily build rather flexible functions, but I'll make sure to give it some extra thought. As to how I ended up in this situation, I tried to give a brief explanation in my comment to Michiel Borkent's answer - not sure if it made any sense though  :)

Comment: You mentioned that you did not want to call h and pass the results to g. Even without knowing the problem domain I can hardly imagine good reasons to do such thing. Functional design is all about breaking big problems into independent small problems. It seems like you are optimizing for a nicer looking function call. If you would describe the specific tasks that g and h fulfill, I could maybe answer with better judgement.

Comment: I'm working on a test automation framework for the system my team is working on, and I'm trying to work out a simple interface for the others (who are not very experienced with Clojure). For them, there would be no point in having the functions nicely composable, especially as h is mostly meant as a helper function to g. I do agree with you however, and after giving it some more thought, I did some redesign, and simply made the externally facing function the composition of the others. One step forward... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simplistic function which may be used exactly as apply, except that the final arg (which should be a map) will be expanded out to :key1 val1 :key2 val2 etc.

```
(defn mapply
  [f & args]
  (apply f (reduce concat (butlast args) (last args))))
```

I'm sure there are more efficient ways to do it, and whether or not you'd want to end up in a situation where you'd have to use such a function is up for debate, but it does answer the original question. Mostly, I'm childishly satisfied with the name...

Answer (score 0):

Nicest solution I have found:

```
(apply g (apply concat my-map))
```